# Selecting max(cursor) Value returns incorrect max from arcpy.da.UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7, cursor

I'm working through some da.UpdateCursor scripts to make updates to a fgdb. Although the script below works successfully as a rule, it returns the incorrect max value from one feature class.

The feature class in question has been rebuilt numerous times but I still get the second highest value returned not the highest. Note this occurs in this feature class on the three columns with values (OBJECTID, Shape_Length, Shape_Area), the only other column is Shape.

Can anyone provide some guidance please as I have researched this and can't get an answer after some hours of experimenting across numerous other feature classes.

My only thought at this point, 'is there a ceiling on max?' given that  min(cursor) returns the lowest value correctly on the three columns.

Using Win 7, ArcGIS 10.2, Python 2.7.5 (yes, I'm in a mixed OS environment).

```
    import arcpy, sys, os
    from os import sep


    ws = env.workspace

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ws +sep+ 'Library_362', "Shape_Area") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            highValue = max(cursor)
            print highValue

    # returns [7693891.489877664]
    # s/be   [10054353.128549]
```

Comment: It sounds crazy but the script works fine, i.e. it prins only once and produces correct answer! Moreover it's enough to move highvalue=... after with statement. No need to iterate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can't test it at the moment, though i'm surprised a cursor can/should be accessed that way? i would think you would want something like:

```
highValue = 0.0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ws +sep+ 'Library_362', "Shape_Area") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] > highValue:
            highValue = row[0]
print highValue # NOTE: print this at end of loop, rather than inside.
```

Comment: Yes that works fine thanks @fluidmotion. It does however create a further mystery for me in that the script I wrote works for all fields I tested in another 20 feature classses in my fgdb and also another 20 or so in a bunch of other fgdb. Puzzling.

Comment: hmmm. As @FelixIP mentioned, the max() could conceivably work - without iterating (actually, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) state that max() accepts an iterable (cursor), not just a list!)...could it be that max is producing the string order rather than the numerical order in some cases?

Answer (score 1):

Your method may work, but it will perform the same action (finding the max in the cursor) for each row.

Here's a version that utilizes list comprehension:

```
highValue = max ([val for val, in arcpy.da.UpdateCursor
                  (ws +sep+ 'Library_362', "Shape_Area")])
```

Comment: Instead of creating a potentially extremely large list in memory, you can pass a generator expression directly to `sum`, `max`, `min`, etc. For example, `sum(x*x for x in xrange(20))`